# Success rate of a player trying to guess a bitstring with given constriants

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients

For work at my university I try to solve a problem.

I have a bit string with given length $len$ and count of active bit $active$

An example could be:

```
1001 0110
```

$len = 8, active = 4$

Now I have a player that knows the $len$ and $active$ of the bit string but not the bit string itself.

My goal is it to calculate the success rate of the player to guess a new bit string that has a hamming distance below $x=0,1,2,3,4,...$

```
1001 0110 <-- 4 active bits
1001 0101 <-- 4 active bits
---------
0000 0011 -> error = 2
```

My approach is to calculate all possible permutations of the bit string with binomial $\binom{len}{active}$.
This gives me the total possibilities of bit strings the player can guess.

Now i need to find the ones that have a hamming distance below the threshold $x$.
Through trying i found out the only even values of $x$ need to be considered.
This is due to the hamming distance. With given bits set to 1 the distance is always incremented by 2.

The problem is the count of guesses of the player that fit the condition.

The cases in which the player wins are:

- He guesses the original bitstring -> 1
- He guesses a string that has a small enough hamming distance

The second part melts my brain.
I tried to work this on an example:

$len = 6, active = 3$
The bitstring is this:

```
011 010
```

If the hamming distance needs to be $x=0$ the player has a chance of $\frac{1}{\binom{6}{3}} = 1/20$

$x = 1$ can be ignored a stated above.

$x=2$ the player needs to guess 2 of the 3 correctly.
The other 1 can be placed randomly.
So the player guesses successful if:

- he hits all tree -> 1
- he hits two -> ??

If he hits two than he can chose the third at random.
This leads to $\binom{3}{2}$ for the 2 correct out of three and $6-2 = 4$ positions for the last one.

Combined:

$\frac{1 + \binom{3}{2} * 6-2}{\binom{6}{3}}$

I tried to come up with a formular that work with higher values of $x, len$ and $active$ but my results so far always fail:

$\frac{1 + \binom{active}{active - (x/2)} * \binom{len - (active - (x/2))}{active - (x/2)} }{\binom{len}{active}}$

Can anyone see a error that i made or give me a hint on how the problem can be solved. Maybe this is a common problem and I have not found the simple solution there is  to it!?

Thanks
Felix

PS: Sorry for my english, a non native speaker here :>

Answer (score 0):

Brute force coding brought the solution to me: https://gist.github.com/effem/419d8bc2ce7403fc3474

And the math solution is as follows:

$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{x/2}{\binom{a}{i}\cdot\binom{l-a}{i}}$ for $\frac{x}{2} \leq l-a$